# Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognised element 'services'. Nested ConfigurationElementCollection

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

I have a following configSection in App.Config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="servicesConfig" type="Admin.Config.ServicesConfig, TestConsole"/>
  </configSections>
  <servicesConfig>
    <serviceGroups>
      <services group="group1">
        <add name="Service1" host="localhost"/>
        <add name="Service2" host="localhost"/>
      </services>
      <services group="groups">
        <add name="Service1" host="localhost"/>
        <add name="Service2" host="localhost"/>
      </services>
    </serviceGroups>
  </servicesConfig>
</configuration>
```

This has been mapped to following Classes in c#

http://pastie.org/1538533

I am getting the following error

Unhandled Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognised element 'services'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Service : ConfigurationElement
```

change Service to **services**.